# Why as.data.frame doing this in R programming?

Tags: r

First of all i would like to tell that I am new to R programming. I was doing some experiment on some R code. I am facing some strange behaviour that I do not expect. I think some one can help me to figure it out.

I ran the following code to read data from a CSV file:

```
normData= read.csv("normData.csv");
```

and my `normData` looks like:

[image]

But When I ran the following code to form a Data Frame:

```
datExpr0 = as.data.frame(t(normData));
```

I get the following data:

[image]

Can some one please tell me, from where the an extra raw (v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6) coming from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using:

```
setNames(as.data.frame(t(normData[-1])), normData[[1]])
```

However, it might be better to see if you can use the `row.names` argument in `read.table` to directly read your "X" as the row names. Then you should be able to directly use `as.data.table(t(...))`.

---

Here's a small example to show what's happening:

Start with a `data.frame` with characters as the first column:

```
df <- data.frame(A = letters[1:3],
                 B = 1:3, C = 4:6)
df
#   A B C
# 1 a 1 4
# 2 b 2 5
# 3 c 3 6
```

When you transpose the entire thing, you also transpose that first column (thereby also creating a character matrix).

```
as.data.frame(t(df))
#   V1 V2 V3
# A  a  b  c
# B  1  2  3
# C  4  5  6
```

So, we drop the column first, and use the values from the column to replace the "V1", "V2"... names.

```
setNames(as.data.frame(t(df[-1])), df[[1]])
#   a b c
# B 1 2 3
# C 4 5 6
```

Comment: @vessilli, glad to hear it helped. Do look into the `row.names` argument in `read.table`/`read.csv` though. It might be a more direct solution, but I can't tell without some sample lines of the actual csv file.